# Is there an implicit conversion in this multiplication?

Tags: numpy

```
In [53]: x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])  
In [55]: x.shape                                                                                                                                    
Out[55]: (3, 2)

In [56]: y = np.array([1,2])
In [58]: y.shape                                                                                                                                    
Out[58]: (2,)

In [59]: np.matmul(x,y)                                                                                                                             
Out[59]: array([ 5, 11, 17])
```

shape (3,2) can be multiplied with shape (2,). Is that because somehow (2,) is implicitly converted into shape (2,1)?

Comment: This should help out - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: It seems not be due to broadcasting. I am wondering how shape (3,2) can be multiplied with shape (2,). Normally, it should be shape (2,1), right?

Comment: If you read it through, you will have a better understanding on how shapes are aligned.